# Principal Ideal and Coset Representatives

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to get my head around what exactly a principal ideal domain means. I know an ideal $I \subseteq R$ is principal if it can be generated by an element, say $c \in R$ so then a principal ideal domain is a domain in which every ideal is principal.

I'm working on a question and I'm not sure how I arrive at the answer or how to actually start the question:

In $\Bbb R[x]$, let $I$ be the principal ideal generated by $g(x)=x^4+3x^3-4$. Consider $a=x^3-x+I$ and $b=2x^2-5+I$ in $\Bbb R[x]/I$. Give a coset representative of degree 3 for their product $ab \in R[x]/I$. Justify your answer.

So from what I know, every element in $I$ can be generated by $g(x)$ (does this mean multiplying and addition?). Then I assume the next step is to multiply $ab$ and then find this coset representative.

If I'm correct, $ab = 2x^5-7x^3+5x + I$ but I'm not sure what to do next.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it meant to say "least" in front of "degree"above?

Comment: sorry, it was supposed to say 'degree 3'. thanks

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the ideal $I = (x^4+3x^3-4)$. In this ideal, we can then write that $$x^4 + I = -3x^3+4 + I.$$ So in the product $ab$ we have:
\begin{align}
ab &= 2x^5-7x^3+5x + I\\
& = 2x(-3x^3+4)-7x^3+5x+I \\
&= -6x^4-7x^3+13x+I\\
&=-6(-3x^3+4)-7x^3+13x+I \\
&= 11x^3+13x-24+I.
\end{align}
So in $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$, we will have $ab = 11x^3+13x-24+I$.

The general idea is to find the remainder of the highest power in the generating element, and then keep substituting that into any element until is has lesser degree.

Comment: Would this be the same as dividing $ab$ by $g(x)$ and then taking the remainder?

Comment: and what's the thought process in the first line of calculations? why did you factor out $2x$? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Yes, this is the same as dividing and taking the remainder. I just tend to use this method as I find the calculations easier, but they are the same processes.

Comment: In the first line I've taken the $2x^5$ and written it as $2x \cdot x^4$ and then written what $x^4$ is in our ring.

Comment: oh I see! and yes you've done this because you want to keep reducing the highest power until it's of degree 3. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: sorry but one last question: why the answer that you got  a coset representative? what's the justification for it? thanks!

Comment: Since $I$ is additive, any coset of $I$ will be of the form $p(x) + I$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial. We can have more than one representative for the same coset, for example if $q(x)$ is in $I$, then $p(x) + q(x) + I$ is also a coset representative, but this question just asked for one with degree $3$.

Answer (score 1):

$ab = 2x^5 - 7x^3 + 5x + I$, but $I$ is generated by $x^4 + 3x^3 - 4$, so contains $2x^5 + 6x^4 - 8x$, meaning that in $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$, we have 
$$\begin{align}2x^5 - 7x^3 + 5x + I &= 2x^5 - 7x^3 + 5x - (2x^5 + 6x^4 - 8x) + I\\
&= -6x^4 - 7x^3 +13x+I \\
&= -6x^4 - 7x^3 +13x+(6x^4+18x^3-24)+I \\
&= 11x^3+13x-24+I
\end{align}$$
So we have a degree 3 polynomial that is represents the same coset as $ab$ inside $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$.  In particular, if two elements $c$, $d$ are in the same coset $R/I$, they satisfy $c-d \in I$, so to do this I just subtracted off multiples of something I know is in $I$ to end up with a degree 3 poly.

Comment: The ideal isn't going to contain $2x^5+6x^4-4x$, I think you meant to multiply the $4$ by $2x$, but forgot the $2$.

Comment: You're correct, my mistake.

Comment: how did you arrive at so contains $2x^5+6x^4−8x$? and why did you specifically use this polynomial? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Going from the first line to the second line also contains a mistake, you've lost the  $-7x^3$ term. Then also from the third to fourth line, you seem to have combined the $13x$ and $39x^3$.

Comment: Oh dear me. I'll edit again carefully this time!